# can't able to call a function using jquery by class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
  $(".questions").append("<a href='#' **`class='jump'`** style='margin-left:3px;' id='"+qData[i].id+"'>"+qData[i].id+"</a>");
} 



$(".jump").on("click",function(){
  alert("hey");
  i = $(this).attr('id');
  alert(i);
  ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ourRequest.open("GET", "http://localhost/project/php/Chapter.php/?id="+i);
  ourRequest.onload = function(){
    ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
    $("#qqq").html(ourData[0].question);
    $("#op1").html(ourData[0].first);
    $("#op2").html(ourData[0].second);
    $("#op3").html(ourData[0].third);
    $("#op4").html(ourData[0].fourth);
  };
  ourRequest.send();
  i++;
});
```

I append links with class name "jump" in a Div and Called a function on onclick of class "jump" but function is not running.

Comment: What should this ** ** do?

Comment: @Jonasw . I think OP thought to make it bold. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly bind event like below. This is the **technique to bind event to elements which gets added in the DOM at run time** or on any event. This we we can delegate event to required future element. i.e. to elements which added in DOM in future.

```
    $("body").on("click",".jump",function(){//change $("body").on("click",".jump"
// you can also use $(document).on("click",".jump"
        alert("hey");
        i = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(i);
        ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ourRequest.open("GET", "http://localhost/project/php/Chapter.php/?id="+i);
        ourRequest.onload = function(){
          ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
          $("#qqq").html(ourData[0].question);
          $("#op1").html(ourData[0].first);
          $("#op2").html(ourData[0].second);
          $("#op3").html(ourData[0].third);
          $("#op4").html(ourData[0].fourth);
        };
    ourRequest.send();
      i++;
    });
```

Comment: If this has helped please mark it as an answer. and a vote

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are appending link to DOM and when you have defined function it was bounded to elements which were there when Dom was loaded.

So you have to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) in jQuery.

Use code like this :

```
$(document).on("click",".jump"function(){
```

Comment: @DeepakJain you're welcome. Please mark answer as correct. Thanks